# Java VM is the operand stack always empty at end of method

Tags: java, jvm, stack

In a Java VM, at the end of a method when it returns does the operand stack contain just the return value (or empty for void methods).  Or could there be other values under the return value that need to be discarded in the stack?

I'm creating each methods frame on the standard C stack.  As shown in this image:

[image]

As you can see, the operand stack in the caller becomes the args in the callee frame.
In the callee frame, would there be "junk" (other than the return value) on the operand stack that needs to be cleaned up before I restore my saved registers?

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own JVM?

Comment: I don't think so. The stack is per frame and I don't see a need, e.g. in exceptional return case to clean it up when it gets destroyed anyways. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6

Comment: The problem is I am using the standard C stack to hold my locals and operand stack.  The "frame" is just pushed on to the C stack as needed.  The operand stack of caller becomes the args/locals of callee.  I need to know if a compiler could leave junk on the operand stack.

Comment: I can easily calculate the current operand stack size, but I just want to know if that is necessary.

Comment: But even a usual C-stack doesn’t work this way. Compiled C code usually creates a frame on function entry which is dropped as a whole, regardless of the place within the function where the function is exited.

Comment: Released my JVM @ github.com/pquiring/jfvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation of [`return`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.return):

> #### operand stack
>
> ... → [empty]
>
> #### Description
>
> … If no exception is thrown, any values on the operand stack of the current frame (§2.6) are discarded.

or [`ireturn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ireturn), respectively:

> #### operand stack
>
> ..., value → [empty]
>
> #### Description
>
> …  If no exception is thrown, value is popped from the operand stack of the current frame (§2.6) and pushed onto the operand stack of the frame of the invoker. Any other values on the operand stack of the current method are discarded.

I think, this is giving enough hints that there might be values on the operand stack that have to be “discarded”, though, in typical implementations, no action is necessary as discarding the stack frame as a whole implies discarding the operand stack.

I’m not sure why this is an obstacle to you. If you really want to get the to the beginning of the stack frame by using the current operand stack position, you’ll need meta information about the stack frame anyway, i.e. you have to know the number of local variables in that frame. Retrieving this information and calculating the stack frame start, can’t be cheaper than retrieving the start of the frame in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I can calculate the size of the operand stack by the number of locals and offset from that.  It's 3 extra little steps but I wanted to know if I could avoid it.

Comment: On your link to ireturn is says "Any other values on the operand stack of the current method are discarded."  That implies there could be extra "junk" on the stack.  I couldn't find that else where.  Thanks.

Comment: That’s what the other link to `return` says as well, only that it doesn’t say “other” because *any* value still on the stack is to be discarded. Besides that, I didn’t think of using the meta information to calculate the operand stack size, as that’s irrelevant anyway, you should base your operations, e.g. saving and restoring the registers, from the start of the stack frame.

Comment: I keep a pointer to the base of the locals, so calculating the stack size is easy.  Now I'm just curious if any compilers do leave "junk" on the stack.  I'll add debug messages and find out once I get to that point.

Comment: Isn’t the pointer to the base of the locals identical to the beginning of the stack frame? That makes removing the stack frame quite easy. I doubt that you will ever encounter such artifacts with common Java compilers, but not encountering them doesn’t preclude their existence. There are also byte code optimizers and obfuscators that might change that.

Comment: Yes, pointer to base of locals = beginning of stack frame.  Also the "this" pointer (unless static) or first argument too.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: The [operand stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2) is part of a frame:

> Each frame (§2.6) contains a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack known as
>   its operand stack.

and frame creation/destruction [corresponds to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) method invocation/completion

> A new frame is created each time a method is invoked. A frame is
>   destroyed when its method invocation completes, whether that
>   completion is normal or abrupt (it throws an uncaught exception).

This does not give much insight about the operand stack when a method returns but  at least it answers your question about the need to clean-up the operand stack: Since it is frame-local, there is no need for a clean-up since the operand stack is discarded along with its frame.

Comment: But all my frames are created on the C stack which is never "discarded" but just popped off the stack as needed.

Comment: @PeterQuiring you didn't mention C stacks  in your original question.

Comment: I added more since there was confusion, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is hard to answer conclusively, because you do not specify precisely what you're asking about.

The specification is publically available https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf (See chapter 2.6.2)

This indicates that the stack may be in arbitrary state, at least when an uncaught exception occurs. I did not see an explicit mention of the return value, but since the return bytecode is specified to return a value from the stack value it *must* be on the stack (chapter 3.5).

The specification is just a description what happens logically. A real VM does not need to translate the specification 1:1 into a memory layout - it only needs to ensure the resulting logic is identical (think of JIT'd code).

Comment: Yes, the specs are somewhat vague which is why I asked.